# Any ideas for Parallel Computing Project?

Tags: parallel-computing, applications

I have to make an application as my Parallel Computing university course project.
The application should make use of parallel processing. Any ideas or examples for these kinds of applications ??

Comment: Welcome to [cs.se]! Unfortunately, your question may notbe  a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. We prefer questions that have objectively correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable topic for study, projects or research is very much a matter of opinion and depends crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing the work and the support that will be available to them. This is a question that you should be asking your professors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ideas for your project. You can parallelize an existing sequential algorithm, which one clearly depends on your interest and/or knowledge of the field. You may also exploit this as an opportunity to learn something new.

## Data mining

- CountSketch
- Count-Min
- HyperLogLog
- Space Saving
- Frequent
- Spectral clustering
- BIRCH
- Singular Value Decomposition
- CHARM (closed frequent itemsets mining)
- EM (Expectation-Maximization) clustering
- CPC (Compressed Probabilistic Counting) Sketch
- Q-Digest (quantiles)

## Nature inspired optimization

- Moth-Flame Optimization Algorithm
- Raven Roosting Optimization Algorithm
- Emperor Penguin Optimization Algorithm
- Shark Smell Optimization
- Grey Wolf Optimization
- Fish School Search
- Dragonfly Algorithm
- Bat Algorithm
- GSA (Gravitational Search Algorithm)

## Numerical algorithms

- tridiagonal linear systems
- numerical integration using Romberg’s method
- Matrix Multiplication: SUMMA Algorithm
- FFT
- Snyder Matrix Multiplication
- Fast Hartley Transform
- Bareiss algorithm (for computing the determinant of a matrix)
- Levinson-Durbin algorithm (for linear systems with Toeplitz matrices)

## Puzzles

- solver for the Aristotle's Number Puzzle (magic exagon of order 3)
- solver for Futoshiki puzzle (board 10 × 10)